# SharePoint online reset ID number every year

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I'm new in SharePoint online.

I've created a list, customized its form and flows.

But my question is aside from deleting the list to reset the ID number is there a way to reset it every year automatically without deleting the list? So that I'm not going to recheck and re-edit the form of the list.

Like for example today 2019 the ID count is over 500+ and by next year 2020 the ID number will reset into 1 or 0. So in short, ID number will reset every end of the year.

My list number is depending on ID number.

Example.

```
eNUM-2019-000
eNUM-2019-001
...
```

then for next year

```
eNUM-2020-000
eNUM-2020-001
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, we can't reset the list item ID directly.

As a workaround, we can save the list as template and create new list base on the template in the new year begin.

Or you can create another Number column and maintain the ID in the new column.